# How I connect my app to mysql server and update my result automatically

Tags: java, android, mysql, sql, sql-server

How I connect my app to my database I am using XAMPP server ? and update my result automatically through server?

Comment: Do you trust the application enough to have it directly connect to your mysql server, or would you want it to connect to your webservice PHP, because you're using XAMPP) and update it there?

Comment: My app is able to connect to sqllite database of eclipse now I want to connect my app to mysql database for storing large amount of data.Thank you for replying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to code a web service in Php or any other language which will return or store data when queried. Take a look at this tutorial [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/). Best of luck!